# GITLAB installation Challenge on CentOS

Tags: gitlab

I installed GITLAB in CentOS 7.4 in cloud environment, I enabled http, hhtps, ssh ports
When I Open the system, I am getting “Apache HTTP server” welcome page not the GIT LAB page, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your environment maybe came with httpd installed, GitLab by default uses nginx.

You can stop and disable httpd, then restart GitLab

```
$ sudo systemctl status httpd
$ sudo systemctl stop httpd
$ sudo systemctl disable httpd

$ sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

Comment: thanks,But when I tried the above way their is no server running, I am getting following error

The server is down or refusing connections

 
Most likely causes:

    * There might be a typing error in the address.
    * The server you are trying to access is down or unavailable.
    * If you clicked on a link, it may be out of date.

What you can try:

    * Retype the address.
    * Wait and try again later.
    * Go back to the previous page

Comment: I stopped the httpd and installed but for that also the first page is nginx
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.

Comment: Check the status of the GitLab processes gitlab-ctl status, also check /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb - especially external_url; make sure it's set.  After updating that file do a gitlab-ctl reconfigure